# Laço de repetição não se comporta como esperado

Tags: python

Estou com dificuldade para fazer um exercício do livro 'Curso intensivo de python de Eric Matthes' o exercícios é o seguinte:

**7.8 – Lanchonete:** Crie uma lista chamada **sandwich_orders** e a preencha com
os nomes de vários sanduíches. Em seguida, crie uma lista vazia chamada
**finished_sandwiches**. Percorra a lista de pedidos de sanduíches com um laço e
mostre uma mensagem para cada pedido, por exemplo, Preparei seu
sanduíche de atum. À medida que cada sanduíche for preparado, transfira-o
para a lista de sanduíches prontos. Depois que todos os sanduíches estiverem
prontos, mostre uma mensagem que liste cada sanduíche preparado.

```
sandwich_orders = ['frango', 'peru', 'queijo', 'presunto']
finished_sandwiches = []

    while finished_sandwiches:
        sandwiches = sandwich_orders.pop()
        finished_sandwiches.append(sandwiches)
        for sandwich in finished_sandwiches:
            print('Preparei seu sanduiche de ' + sandwich)
```

Quando eu executo o arquivo no vscode ele me responde isso:

```
PS C:\Users\Pedro Moraes\Desktop\stuff\Exercicios\python> & "C:/Users/Pedro Moraes/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python38-32/python.exe" "c:/Users/Pedro Moraes/Desktop/stuff/Exercicios/python/lanchonete.py"
```

Ele não "printa" nada no terminal.

O que eu devo fazer?

Comment: O programa está agindo como esperado. `finished_sandwiches`  está vazio, então o `while finished_sandwiches` não tem nada a fazer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

O programa está agindo como devia. `finished_sandwiches` está vazio (`= []`), então o `while finished_sandwiches` não tem nada a fazer.

Agora, se você trocar o while por `while sandwich_orders:`, a coisa muda. Afinal, você quer iterar sobre os pedidos e não sobre os prontos (que não existem).

```
sandwich_orders = ['frango', 'peru', 'queijo', 'presunto']
finished_sandwiches = []

while sandwich_orders:
   sandwiches = sandwich_orders.pop()
   finished_sandwiches.append(sandwiches)
```

E outra coisa, tirei o `for` dentro do `while`, senão você vai avisar todas as vezes que fizer cada um dos sanduiches (a nao ser que a intenção seja essa, claro).

```
sandwich_orders = ['frango', 'peru', 'queijo', 'presunto']
finished_sandwiches = []

while sandwich_orders:
   sandwiches = sandwich_orders.pop()
   finished_sandwiches.append(sandwiches)    

for sandwich in finished_sandwiches:
   print('Preparei seu sanduiche de ' + sandwich)
```

Veja funcionando no **[IDEONE](https://ideone.com/OBwpMC)**.

Comment: Era apenas um erro na IDE mas mesmo a sim obrigado

Comment: @PedroMoraesMilagres Então tem mais coisa errada, porque um código logicamente errado não deveria ser um "erro na IDE".

Comment: eu reiniciei o pc e funcionou o codigo